# Applying CellTemplate for dyncamic columns in Telerik WPF

Tags: wpf, gridview, data-binding

In my WPF project I am triyng to bind an object to every generated column, then in CellTemplate specify, how this object should be shown in UI, but I have problems accesing object properites in this template.

I am generating columns like this

```
 var gridViewDataColumn = new GridViewDataColumn()
                                     {
                                         UniqueName = uniqueName,
                                         Header = header,
                                         Width = GridViewLength.Auto,
                                         DataMemberBinding = new Binding
                                                             {
                                                                 Source = ViewModel.MyCollection,
                                                                 Path = new PropertyPath("ObjectDictionary"),
                                                                 Converter = new IdToCellValueConverter(),
                                                                 ConverterParameter = id
                                                             },
                                         CellTemplate = cellTemplate,
                                     };
```

Converter is simply gets a value of ObjectDictionary by key = id. ObjectDictionary is `Dictionary<int, MyObject>`, and MyObject contains `int property1` and `int property2`. cellTemplate is

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyObjectDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type models:MyObject}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding property1}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding propery2}"/>
            <Button Label="MyButton"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But this solution does not work - it renders MyButton in each column, but MyObject properties are not appearing in UI.